# pandas first_valid_index() as integer key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with an index as a date string like so:
'2015-07-15'

and another column along side it with a value associated with the dates.

When I use to find out when the column first time equals 5:

```
df[df['Column'] == 5].first_valid_index()
```

it gives me back

```
'2020-12-19'
```

instead I want to know the exact integer index number of this occurence rather than the Date index itself so I can use the .iloc method to specify this index.

How would I do so?  thank you

Comment: Please share a sample input dataframe with expected output for clarity.

Comment: `df.reset_index().loc[lambda x: x['Column']==5].first_valid_index()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) before so that you can get your integer index.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df[df['Column'] == 5].first_valid_index()
```

Alternate way without resetting index would be using [get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html). Assuming your data atleast contain 1 value

```
df.index.get_loc(df.index[df['Column'] == 5][0])
```

Combination of both would look like,

```
df.index.get_loc(df[df['Column'] == 5].first_valid_index())
```